# One selectable RadioButton inside DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button, datalist

I am trying to implement multiple choice questions within my web application. I have datalist within a datalist. First datalist contains questions, second datalist contains choice, only one choice should be selectable at a time. I am using radio button. Even though I have set RadioButton.GroupName property, I can't make them selectable one at a time.

Please help.

Comment: is this asp.net? plz show relevant code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a RadioButtonList, only one RadioButton of a RadioButtonList can be selected.  Use the RadioButtonList instead of the second DataList.

Answer (score 0):

Use CheckBox instead of RadioButton

Comment: I can not use check boxes, radio button are the requirement.

Comment: @Ashar: Set different `RadioButton.GroupName` for each radio button